# Show if $X_n$ goes to infinity $P(X_n < M \text{ i.o}) = 0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

We are asked to show:

if a random variable sequence $X_n \to +\infty $ almost surely  then  $ P(X_n < M \text{ i.o}) = 0 \ \forall \ M \gt 0$

I try show this using $E(X_n) = \infty $

$E(X_n) = \int_{X_n < M} X_n dP + \int_{X_n \ge M} X_n dP= \infty$

$\int_{X_n < M} X_n dP \le M\int_{A_n: (X_n < M)}dP \le M\sum P(A_n)$

Since $M\sum P(A_n) \le \infty \implies P(A_n \text{ i.o}) = 0$ by Borell Cantelli I.

I'm not sure if the above is correct though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything like an integral or an expectation for this.

If $X_n\to \infty$, then with probability one $X_n\ge M$ eventually so with probability zero $X_n<M$ infinitely often.

Formally, let $M > 0$. Then we know that
$$\{\omega \in \Omega: \lim_n X_n(\omega) = \infty\}\subseteq \{\omega \in \Omega: X_n(\omega) \ge M \mathrm{\ eventually}\}$$

Hence,
$$\mathbb{P}\{\omega \in \Omega: X_n(\omega) \ge M \mathrm{\ eventually}\} = 1.$$
Next, note that
$$\{\omega \in \Omega:  X_n(\omega) \ge M \mathrm{\ eventually}\}^c = \{\omega \in \Omega: X_n(\omega) < M \mathrm{\ infinitely \ often}\}$$
and thus
$$\mathbb{P}\{\omega \in \Omega: X_n(\omega) < M \mathrm{\ infinitely \ often}\} = 1- \mathbb{P}\{\omega \in \Omega:  X_n(\omega) \ge M \mathrm{\ eventually}\} = 0$$
as desired.

Comment: I want to show this formally, it follows intuitively but it needs to be a rigorous proof of the end result

Comment: @mathcompguy I added more details. Let know if it is not clear.

Comment: Why would the first subset hold that $X_n(w) = \inf$ is a subset of $X_n(w) \ge \ M$ eventually?

Comment: @mathcompguy $x_n \to +\infty$ means by definition that $\forall M > 0: \exists N: \forall n \ge N: x_n \ge M$. In words: a sequence converges to infinity if it can be made arbitrarily large by looking far enough in the sequence.

Comment: I see so is the first subset simply the point where X = inf, which is a subset of the 2nd set since inf > M which will occur as you say at some point N s.t. n >= N?

Comment: @mathcompguy If $X_n(\omega) \to \infty$, then $X_n(\omega)\ge M$ for large enough $n$, i.e. $X_n(\omega)$ eventually.